# How to deal with very high current to DC motor

Tags: power-electronics, dc-motor, high-current, component-selection, soft-starter

I am using a pickup truck starter motor to build a small crane-like loading arm. I want to control the direction of rotation using an H-bridge, however, when I turn on the mechanism the motor has a very high starting current (approximately 550 A) and a steady state current of 280 A. I also have the problem of overdriving due to the initial current spike. I have read that a soft starter can solve this problem, but the experiments I have done with different circuits always end up burning the electronic components.

I am using a car battery as a power source.

What components would you recommend to handle the high current or what strategy could I use to finish my project?

Comment: Should be nothing wrong with using an H-bridge if the FETs are sized and driven appropriately.  It's all in the details.  Can you add a schematic of the circuit you have tried?

Comment: Starter motors are usually built to run for very short periods of time. If you run it for a longer time, you may run into heat issues.

Comment: It might be easier and cheaper do get a high-current brushed DC motor controller. This will incorporate all the necessary features: forward reverse control, soft-start/acceleration control, short-circuit and fault handling. Some might even have the battery charger built in.  Basically, you need the technology that runs electric powered fork lifts.

Comment: A starter motor isn’t a good choice. Look into hydraulics I think. Know any low riders? They’re experts on this, seriously.